# watchdog.observers.Observer works in Windows, works in docker on Linux, does not work in docker on Windows

Tags: python, docker, watchdog

I have an interesting problem that is driving me nuts. I have a python program that is using watchdog.observers.Observer.  This program (aka watcher) watches a folder and responds when files appear in it.  I have another program (aka parser) which periodically populates the watched folder with files.

1. When the watcher program runs in Windows and the parser runs in a docker container on Windows, there is happiness.
2. When the watcher program runs in a docker container on a Linux box and the parser runs in another  docker container on the Linux box, there is happiness.
3. When the watcher program runs in a docker container on Windows and the parser runs in another docker container on Windows, happiness is not achieved.  The parser populates the folder with files, but the watcher never observes them.

Here's my watcher code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
   
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from event_handler import ImagesEventHandler
from constants import ROOT_FOLDER, IMAGES_FOLDER, CWD


class ImagesWatcher:
    def __init__(self, src_path):
        self.__src_path = src_path
        print(self.__src_path)
        self.__event_handler = ImagesEventHandler()
        self.__event_observer = Observer()
        print("********** Inside ImagesWatcher --init__ method just after instantiating ImagesEventHandler and Observer **************")

    def run(self):
        print("********** Inside ImagesWatcher run method **************")
        self.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.stop()

    def start(self):
        print("********** Inside ImagesWatcher start method **************")
        self.__schedule()
        self.__event_observer.start()

    def stop(self):
        print("********** Inside ImagesWatcher stop method **************")
        self.__event_observer.stop()
        self.__event_observer.join()

    def __schedule(self):
        print("********** Inside ImagesWatcher __schedule method **************")
        print(self.__src_path)
        self.__event_observer.schedule(
            self.__event_handler,
            self.__src_path,
            recursive=True
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else CWD
    src_path = os.path.abspath(src_path)
    watch_path = os.path.join(src_path, ROOT_FOLDER)
    watch_path = os.path.join(watch_path, IMAGES_FOLDER)
    print('watch_path: ' + watch_path)

    if not os.path.exists(watch_path):
        os.makedirs(watch_path)
        print('just created: ' + watch_path)

    ImagesWatcher(watch_path).run()
```

Here's the associated event handler code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from lambda_function import lambda_handler
from time import sleep
from os.path import dirname, abspath

class ImagesEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self,):
        print("********** Inside event handler __init__ method **************")
    
    def on_created(self, event):
        print("********** Inside event handler on_created method **************")
        self.process(event)

    def process(self, event):
        print("********** Inside event handler process method **************")
        sleep(2)
        image = Image.open(event.src_path)
        tracking_dir=os.path.join(dirname(dirname(abspath(event.src_path))),'Tracking')
        print("********************  tracking_dir: ' + tracking_dir + ' ********************")
        lambda_handler(image,tracking_dir)
```

The stop method of the watcher is never executed.  The init method of the event handler is executed, but neither the on_created nor the process methods are executed.

Here's how I build and run the docker containers:

```
docker build -t watcher -f docker/watcher/Dockerfile . 
docker run -d --network onprem_network -v c:\My_MR:/code/My_MR --name watcher watcher 

docker build -t parser -f docker/parser/Dockerfile . 
docker run -d --network onprem_network -v c:\My_MR:/code/My_MR --name parser parser
```

My watcher Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip -r /requirements.txt && mkdir /code 
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN apt update && apt-get update && apt install tesseract-ocr -y && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
CMD ["python", "/code/watcher.py"]
```

My parser Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip -r /requirements.txt && mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN apt update && apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg -y
CMD ["python", "/code/parser.py"]
```

My requirements.txt:

```
Pillow == 5.4.1
gql == 3.0.0a5
matplotlib == 3.0.3
numpy == 1.16.2
opencv_python == 4.4.0.44
pandas == 0.24.2
pytesseract == 0.2.6
python_ffmpeg_video_streaming == 0.1.14
watchdog == 2.0.2
requests
tesseract
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the two containers?

Comment: I added that to the post and I changed the name of populator to parser.

Comment: if a directory is mounted on both containers, then the behaviour should be exactly similar to the behaviour without docker

Comment: That's what I was expecting.

Comment: Which Docker for Windows backend are you using, Hyper-V or WSL 2?

Comment: I'm using WSL2 , I suppose I could try hyper v?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying API that watchdog uses to monitor linux filesystem events is called inotify. The [Docker for Windows WSL 2 backend documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#best-practices) notes:

> Linux containers only receive file change events (“inotify events”) if the original files are stored in the Linux filesystem.

The directory you're mounting, `c:\My_MR`, resides on the Windows file system and thus inotify inside the watcher container doesn't work.

Instead, you can run docker from **inside your WSL 2 default distribution** with a linux filesystem path, e.g., `~/my_mr`:

```
docker run -d --network onprem_network -v ~/my_mr:/code/My_MR --name watcher watcher 
docker run -d --network onprem_network -v ~/my_mr:/code/My_MR --name parser parser
```

This directory can be accessed from Windows while that WSL 2 distribution is running using the `\\wsl$\` network path, i.e., `\\wsl$\<Distro name>\home\<username>\my_mr` (more info [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/)). Accordingly, I believe `docker run` could also be used from Windows using the `\\wsl$\` path with `-v`.

Comment: I will try your suggestion shortly.  However, switching desktop docker back to hyper-v fixed the issue.

Comment: Your solution also worked.  How do I determine the Distro name?  Thanks!

Comment: wsl.exe -l -v  gives the distro

Comment: Right, `wsl -l -v` should do the trick. Docker for Windows by default integrates with the default distribution only, which can be changed with `wsl -s`. Additionally, you can set Docker to integrate with other distros through the dashboard: `Settings > Resources > WSL Integration`.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to use [Docker Windows Volume Watcher](https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher).
The Python script oversee folder bindings of Docker containers running on Windows. This script actively monitors these bindings and updates the associated containers with file modifications.

**Install using `pip` (supports Python 2 & 3):**

```bash
pip install docker-windows-volume-watcher
```

**Once installed, you can customize your monitoring preferences:**

- Monitor All Directory Bindings of All Containers:

  ```bash
  docker-volume-watcher
  ```
- Monitor Only Bindings of a Specific Container:

  ```bash
  docker-volume-watcher container_name
  ```
- Monitor Only a Specific Binding of a Container to a Host Directory:

  ```bash
  docker-volume-watcher container_name C:\some\directory
  ```

**Limitations:**

- The script doesn't propagate to container file deletion events.
- The script requires `stat` and `chmod` utils to be installed in the container.

For further details see following resources.

- [Discussion on Docker Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/file-system-watch-does-not-work-with-mounted-volumes/12038/9)
- [Blog Post on Docker for Windows Watch Bindings](http://blog.subjectify.us/miscellaneous/2017/04/24/docker-for-windows-watch-bindings.html)

**Alternative Approach: Using Watchdog and PollingObserver():**

Another solution is to use the class [`PollingObserver`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.observers.polling.PollingObserver).
While this approach provides flexibility, bear in mind that it might exhibit slower performance when monitoring multiple files and folders simultaneously.

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = PollingObserver()
    # Limit the number of files by setup multiple schedule
    observer.schedule(event_handler, '/folder/subfolder') # All files in a subfolder
    observer.schedule(event_handler, '/folder/file') # A file
    observer.schedule(event_handler, '/folder/file2') # A file
    # etc...
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```